# HTTP заголовки: параметр must-revalidate

Tags: http

Добрый день!

Подскажите пожалуйста, что означает параметр  `must-revalidate` в этой строке кода:

```
header('Cache-Control:no-store,no-cache,must-revalidate');
```

В мануале не  нашел.

Answer (score 6):

[тут](http://www.http11.ru/post.php?post=6)

must-revalidate Эта директива вынуждает кэш провести дополнительную проверку актуальности ресурса на сервере-источнике, если он не уверен в его актуальности. Если прокси-сервер не может осуществить проверку актуальности на сервере-источнике (например, если прокси-сервер не может связаться с Web-сервером), то кэш должен вернуть клиенту не устаревший ответ, а сообщение об ошибке. Различие между директивой must-revalidate и похожей на первый взгляд директивой no-cache заключается в том, что директива must-revalidate накладывает менее строгие ограничения. Директива no-cache строго предписывает при каждом запросе ресурса проверять его актуальность, не зависимо от того, устарел ответ в кэше или нет. Директива must-revalidate позволяет прокси-серверу не выполнять проверку актуальности, если он уверен, что его копия сообщения актуальна. Об этом он может судить по другим директивам ответа и заголовкам ответа. Подобное поведение оставляет небольшую вероятность того, что возвращенный ответ может отличаться от ответа исходного-сервера.
Директива must-revalidate допускает сохранение ответа, по гарантирует, что устаревшие ответы будут обновляться. Однако ответ, который кэш считает обновленным, может быть уже изменен на сервере-источнике. Это различие между директивами no-cache и must-revalidate является ключевым для понимания необходимости обеих директив. Директива no-store вообще исключает кэширование. В случае no-cache существует возможность кэширования, но отсутствует риск возвращения ответа, который уже изменен. В случае must-revalidate существует реальная возможность кэширования и не существует возможности устаревания, хотя остается возможность возвращения ответа, который уже был изменен.

Необходимость этой директивы становится очевидной в свете существования директивы запроса max-stale, которая допускает возможность возвращения устаревшего ответа. Директива must-revalidate является предписанием со стороны сервера-источника игнорировать директивы запроса max-stale и возвращать всегда только актуальный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Выключает клиентский кеш.